# Django annotate with casted variable

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, django-queryset, django-annotate

i want to achieve something complex with a django queryset.
My model looks like this:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    #Model Variables
    year = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Unfortunately,

> score' can't change from CharField() to FloatField()

, it should be kept as a String.

What i need is to sum all scores by year and month. I tried something like this to group all scores with no great success.

```
values = Mymodel.objects.all().values(
    'year', 'month').annotate(Sum('score')).order_by('year', 'month')
```

I tried to cast 'score' before use annotate by doing this.

```
values = Mymodel.objects.all().annotate(
        scoreFloat=Cast('score', FloatField())
    ).values('year', 'month').annotate(
        Sum('scoreFloat')).order_by('year', 'month')
```

Once again with no success, since i am getting a KeyError for scoreFloat parameter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use `charfield` anyway? If something is numerical, store it in a numerical type object. It is horrible modeling to use `CharField`s for that.

Comment: You are right, but i can't change it now, as i'll probably break a lot of working features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second query you should add to the values new field from first annotate:

```
Mymodel.objects.annotate(as_float=Cast('score', FloatField())
    ).values('year', 'month', 'as_float'
    ).order_by('year', 'month'
    ).annotate(sumscore=Sum('as_float')).values('year', 'month', 'sumscore')
```

Comment: This code returns my several objects with the same month, for example
a) 'year': 2018, 'sumscore': 5, 'month': 4
b) 'year': 2018, 'sumscore': 3, 'month': 5
c) 'year': 2018, 'sumscore': 7, 'month': 5 

as long b and c belongs to the same month i want somehow to be like this:
a) 'year': 2018, 'sumscore': 5, 'month': 4
b) 'year': 2018, 'sumscore': 10, 'month': 5 (previous b+c)

Comment: Unfortunately the casting is not working, i am getting exact the same output as previous. If i change score from char to float even without casting (obviously) the queryset works properly. So that leaves me no option, score changed to float.

Comment: strange, i generate test data and all works fine, please add code to generate data like yours inside the question

Comment: Yeap you're right, my fault. Just forgot to change the name in the first annotation.
It works now.

Comment: glad to help you!